# how to limit number ranges in textfields (swift4)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

The code below limits the user to enter into the textfeld just numbers. What I am trying to do is limit the user to enter a number between -359 to 359. No letters just a number between that range.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var juju : UITextField!

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
        let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
        let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
        return string == numberFiltered
    }
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy I dont think this should be duplicate because its a if statement depending on a number range.

Comment: Your goal is to ensure the text entered into a text field is an integer within a specific range. That's what the duplicate and its answers do as well. Though you need both a min and max value. That a trivial change to the existing answers.